# How can I resize the images?

Tags: graphics, includegraphics, sidewaysfigure

I introduced these images into my latex work. I want to increase the size of the images but when I do this they do not align properly.

```
\begin{figure*}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1.0in]{images/41025.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1.0in]{images/groundTruth41025.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.15\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1.0in]{images/imageBest41025.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \\
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1.0in]{images/43033.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}% 
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1.0in]{images/groundTruth43033.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.15\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1.0in]{images/imageBest43033.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \caption{Images.}
\end{figure*}
```

How can I increase the images size without moving? I want to have 3 images side by side

[image]

Comment: As long as you make them the same `height`, why wouldn't they line up (they do now).

Comment: What does "do not align properly" mean? Do you refer to the slightly different horizontal white spaces between adjacent images?

Comment: How can I increase the images size without moving? I want to have 3 images side by side

Comment: your three subfigure total 0.65 of the text width, why just that amount? you can make them all bigger and still fit three on a line?

Answer (score 1):

I know two options to easily create a pleasant layout.

(1) using the `subfigure` environment, or

(2) relying on `tabular`, which frankly seems much simpler.

I added the length `\figwidth` which allows you to change the width of the figures and see how they fit on the page.

[image: a]

[image: b]

The prototype assumed that the leftmost figure is a square 2/3 the width of the other figures.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text    
\usepackage[left=1.2in, right=1.2in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}

\newlength{\figwidth}
\setlength{\figwidth}{1.0in}

\begin{document}
            
1. \kant[1]
    
\begin{figure*}[h]
    \centering  
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\figwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=.66\figwidth,width=\figwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hspace*{10pt}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\figwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=.66\figwidth,width=\figwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hspace*{10pt}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.66\figwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=.66\figwidth,width=.66\figwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{subfigure}%

    \vspace*{10pt}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\figwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=.66\figwidth,width=\figwidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{subfigure}% 
    \hspace*{10pt}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\figwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=.66\figwidth,width=\figwidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hspace*{10pt}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.66\figwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=.66\figwidth,width=0.66\figwidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \caption{Images with subfigure.}
\end{figure*}

    3. \kant[3]
\newpage
    
\begin{figure*}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \includegraphics[height=.66\figwidth,width=\figwidth]{example-image-a}&
        \includegraphics[height=.66\figwidth,width=\figwidth]{example-image-a}&
        \includegraphics[height=.66\figwidth,width=0.66\figwidth]{example-image-a}  \\[6pt] %vertical space between the rows
        \includegraphics[height=.66\figwidth,width=\figwidth]{example-image-b}&
        \includegraphics[height=.66\figwidth,width=\figwidth]{example-image-b}&
        \includegraphics[height=.66\figwidth,width=0.66\figwidth]{example-image-b}  \\
    \end{tabular}
        \caption{Images with tabular.}
\end{figure*}

2. \kant[2]
    
\end{document}
```

This is what you get changing `\figwidth` from `1.8in` to `1in`. See how with the `tabular` the vertical and horizontal separation does not need to be re-equalized.

[image: c]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to place each image inside a `subfigure` environment if you don't plan on indexing them. As such, just insert the images as-is with a `\space` (or some other width) between them:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=1in]{example-image-a}\space
    \includegraphics[height=1in]{example-image-b}\space
    \includegraphics[height=1in]{example-image-1x1}
  
  \includegraphics[height=1in]{example-image-c}\space
    \includegraphics[height=1in]{example-image}\space
    \includegraphics[height=1in]{example-image-1x1}
    
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

From here it should be straight-forward to adjust the height to something suitable for your needs.

---

If you want the images to span the maximum possible width, then set them using some comfortable measure between them, then `\resizebox` the entire row to fit `\linewidth`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
    \includegraphics[height=1in]{example-image-a}\space
      \includegraphics[height=1in]{example-image-b}\space
      \includegraphics[height=1in]{example-image-1x1}}
  
  \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
    \includegraphics[height=1in]{example-image-c}\space
      \includegraphics[height=1in]{example-image}\space
      \includegraphics[height=1in]{example-image-1x1}}
    
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```